# Chrome addressbar dropdown has extra white padding on both sides

Tags: google-chrome, browser

After a hard restart chrome address bar now has weird whitespace padding on both sides. I have tried uninstall / reinstall with no luck. Has anyone faced this issue and would kindly recommend a fix?

[image]

Comment: This UI change was introduced in Chrome 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an intentional UI change that was introduced in Chrome 29.

According to the bug report [Omnibox popup styling change: necessary?](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=276746), it is by design:

> Thanks for the report. This is by design to match the pop-up styling with other platforms.

[Other bug reports](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264182) also indicate that this is a desired change that isn't customizable.

Comment: thank you clarifying was going crazy trying to revert this. guess have to live with it for now.